# How to round a number in a String to nearest million

Tags: java, string, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to round a number in a String to the nearest million in Java. 
String namevalue `362073133410.28625`.
I need Output `$362,073`

This Data `362073133410.28625` comes from database and value `$362,073` is UI value.

```
// Database query to get value
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
while (rs.next()){
    String mytotal = rs.getString(1);                                       
    System.out.println(mytotal);

    // Convert String to float 
    float result = Float.parseFloat(mytotal);       
    System.out.println(result+ " convert valueOf to int");

    // round of to million  
    System.out.println(Math.round(result)+" Result 1");}
```

OUTPUT

```
362073133410.28625
3.62073129E11 convert valueOf to int
2147483647 Result 1
```

EXPECT result should be `362,073`

Comment: And (not) coincidentally 2147483647 in the last print is the largest 32 bit signed int value :). Just delete the float by 1M, and store in an int.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validating Database with UI numbers count convert in UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55657201/validating-database-with-ui-numbers-count-convert-in-ui)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use bigdecimal's for your purpose. Below is the approach for solving your problem:

```
String mytotal = "362073133410.28625";                                     
System.out.println(mytotal);

// Convert String to float 
BigDecimal result = new BigDecimal(mytotal);
System.out.println(result+ " convert valueOf to int");

// round of to million  

 System.out.println(result.divide(new BigDecimal("1000000")).setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)+" Result 1");

// System.out.println(result.divide(new BigDecimal("1000000000")).setScale(3, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)+" Result 1");
```

Comment: System.out.println(result.divide(new BigDecimal("1000000")).setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)+" Result 1");